# Database with cookiecutter flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, cookiecutter

I want to use cookiecutter-flask template to create a local interface for a python app. I want to create a registration system with a database.

You can create a cookiecutter project by running
`cookiecutter https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask.git`

I edited .env by putting :
`DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///dev.db`

Then I filled the database dev.db by creating a table *users* using command shell :

`sqlite3 dev.db`

`CREATE TABLE users ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), active BOOLEAN NOT NULL, is_admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL );`

I don't understand why when I want to register a new user, I get `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users`

I tried to create a new database, completely delete the project and make a new one.
I also tried to use absolute path but it created a new error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file`

Comment: There is common pitfall with SQlite: If you give the wrong filename a new empty file will be created. So, make sure to use the right file name, using an absolute path might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :
I had to run in the shell

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'dev.db')
```

I assume you have a dev.db file in your project folder. Then the correct way to tell flask and sqlite where this file is located is to youse an absolute path as shown above